# inotify - how to find out which user has modified file?

Tags: linux, filesystems, filestream, inotify

I'm looking for guidance on how to find out which user has modified a particular file. While inotify is great to get notification when a particular file is touched, how do I figure out which user has modified that file? I can think of using `lsof` but I'm afraid that it may not be as "realtime" as I want and/or it might be too much of a tax on resources. By realtime, I mean that if a user simply executes a `touch` command on a file, by the time I run `lsof` on file, it may not be picked up by `lsof`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use [audit deamon](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/auditd.8.html):

```
sudo apt-get install auditd
```

Choose a file to monitor

```
touch /tmp/myfile
```

Add audit for write and attribute change (`-p wa`):

```
sudo auditctl -w /tmp/myfile -p wa -k my-file-changed
```

The file is touched by some user:

```
touch /tmp/myfile
```

Check audit logs:

```
sudo ausearch -k my-file-changed | tail -1
```

You can see the `UID` of the user who run the command in the output

> type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1313055675.066:57): arch=c000003e syscall=2
>   success=yes exit=3 a0=7ffffb6744dd a1=941 a2=1b6 a3=7ffffb673bb0
>   items=1 ppid=3428 pid=4793 auid=4294967295 **uid=1000** gid=1000 euid=1000
>   suid=1000 fsuid=1000 egid=1000 sgid=1000 fsgid=1000 tty=pts1
>   ses=4294967295 comm="touch" exe="/bin/touch" key="my-file-changed"

For details of usage see [man pages](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man8/auditd.8.html) or this [sample guide](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-audit-files-to-see-who-made-changes-to-a-file.html).

Answer (score 4):

If you add `-i` option in the earlier command, you will get output in more human readable format. You will get the uid converted to the real username in the server.

```
ausearch -k my-file-changed -i | tail -1
```