# Alert when z file on linux server has been changed by x user

Tags: shell

```
Alert when z file on linux server has been changed by x user.
#/bin/sh
old_time=`stat -c %z /var/spool/cron/root` 
  if [[ "$new_time" != "$old_time" ]]; 
    then 
      echo -e "Changes has been made in Cron file" | mail -s "Modification alert" abhinav.dixit@xyz.com 
    echo -e "$old_time" 
    echo -e "$new_time" 
  else 
    echo "no change" 
 fi
```

Actually i want to track the user who make any change in z file where z file is accessed by n number of users. I am trying with above script atleast to get an alert when z file is changed. I have no idea how to track which user has changed it.

Answer (score 1):

The `inotifywait` utility supplied with [inotify-tools](http://sourceforge.net/projects/inotify-tools/) will help you capture the event without polling:

```
while inotifywait -e modify /var/spool/cron/root; do

done
```

---

[SO: inotify - how to find out which user has modified file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6920812/inotify-how-to-find-out-which-user-has-modified-file#7023931) suggests using the audit daemon to track file modifications by user.